# Plot Shapely LineStrings overlayed by Points in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, shapely

I'm trying to display points over line strings to debug whether there are multiple points on the same line:

```
def to_shapely(points: list[point]):
    return shapely.ops.unary_union([
        shapely.geometry.LineString(points),
        shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(points)
    ])

to_shapely([(0,0), (2,2), (1,0.5)])
```

This only displays the linestrings however. Is there a way to overlay the points on the linestrings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want a [`GeometryCollection`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.GeometryCollection.html) and not a `unary_union` (that returns a single geometry) :

```
import shapely

def to_shapely(points):
    return shapely.geometry.GeometryCollection([
        shapely.geometry.LineString(points),
        shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(points)
    ])

to_shapely([(0,0), (2,2), (1,0.5)])
```

[image]